# Need to convert string yyyymmdd to date yyyymmdd format in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to change '20190622' string type  to 20190622 date type ?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('20190622',)], ['t'])
df.printSchema()
root
|-- t: string (nullable = true)
df1 = df.select(F.to_date(df.t, 'yyyyMMdd').alias('dt'))
```

when i change the format its changing the format.
df1.printSchema()
root
|-- dt: date (nullable = true)

```
df1.show()
+----------+ 
|        dt|
+----------+
|2019-06-22|
+----------+
```

Expected output 20190622 in date data type.

Comment: Why do you think that's not what it is?

Comment: Date type columns can only be displayed as `yyyy-MM-dd`. It's how Spark works. If you want other date formats, unfortunately you have to use a string.

Comment: This looks correct to me, you successfully converted it to `date` type. Output in show is using default format. Now it's converted you can use other date functions to e.g. add days, subtract days, extract month or year etc... If you want to convert it back to string again with custom formatting, you can use the `date_format` function.

Comment: why does this matter? I mean, it's just the representation of the Java date object, anything beyond has to be done in the client code anyways. And for processing there is obviously almost always a benefit of having it in its most specific datatype. Especially once it comes to application of filters etc